# How to access window.location in environment.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In my development setup i use local network resources. So i have to adapt some environment urls depending on my network (home / work) like this:

```
ENV.APP.image_path = home ? 'http://home.server' : "http://work.server";
```

Is it possible to use `window.location` in `config/environment.js` to change this urls automatically?

Comment: `config/environment.js` is used by `ember-cli`, so it is running in Node.js context. The best option, if you create a simple `service` which would access to the `window.location`, so you can use this service where you need... brute force solution is accessing window.location directly, but in this case you would use a global variable more times, which is not recommended.

Comment: Trying to use `window.location` results in the following error:
`The Broccoli Plugin: [ConfigLoader] failed with:
ReferenceError: window is not defined`
I don't know how to inject a service in this file.

Comment: A `service`, like a normal `Ember.Service`, so it will part of the generated frontend Ember application, which is running in your browser... Ember CLI, broccoli, environment file are running in node.js context, only tools for generating your frontend application, so they will not have access to your browser window.

Comment: Probably, the best option that you create two new environments with one param and hardcode your office and home url. You can launch your ember dev environment with `ember s --environment office` or `ember s --environment home`. You can import that hardcoded url where you would like to use. However, I would consider to avoid this kind of external dependency, because if your app so heavily depend on something, and you cannot encapsulate, it means, some architectural step is still missing.